# I keep getting stale data from the database when I change the query parameter

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and working on a homework assignment. When I click the link in the `<aside>`, the data is supposed to update. Clicking the link just updates the query parameter in the address bar. The query parameter is updating just fine but the data is staying the same.

Here is the relevant code:

```
// index.php

<?php
require_once('database.php');

// Get category ID
$course_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'course_id',
    FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if ($course_id == NULL || $course_id == FALSE) {
    $course_id = 'cs601';
}

// Get name for selected category
$queryCourse = 'SELECT * FROM sk_courses WHERE courseID = :course_id';
$queryCourseStatement = $db->prepare($queryCourse);
$queryCourseStatement->bindValue(':course_id', $course_id);
$queryCourseStatement->execute();

$course = $queryCourseStatement->fetch();
$course_name = $course['courseName'];

$queryCourseStatement->closeCursor();


// Get all courses
$queryCourses = 'SELECT * FROM sk_courses ORDER BY courseID';
$queryCoursesStatement = $db->prepare($queryCourses);
$queryCoursesStatement->execute();

$courses = $queryCoursesStatement->fetchAll();

$queryCoursesStatement->closeCursor();

// Get products for selected category
$queryStudents = 'SELECT * FROM sk_students WHERE courseID = :course_id ORDER BY studentID';
$queryStudentsStatement = $db->prepare($queryStudents);
$queryStudentsStatement->bindValue(':course_id', $course_id);
$queryStudentsStatement->execute();

$students = $queryStudentsStatement->fetchAll();

$queryStudentsStatement->closeCursor();

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>MMelvin HW5</title>
</head>
<body>
<main class="container">
    <h1 class="display-6">Course Manager</h1>
    <hr>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">

        <aside>
            <h2 class="display-6">Courses</h2>
            <nav>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <?php foreach ($courses as $course) : ?>
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <a href="?course_id=<?php echo $course['courseID']; ?>">
                                <?php echo $course['courseID']; ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </aside>

        <section>
            <h2 class="display-6"><?php echo $course_id . ' - ' . $course_name; ?></h2>

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">First Name</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Last Name</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Email</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($students as $student) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $student['firstName']; ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $student['lastName']; ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $student['email']; ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <form action="delete_student.php" method="post">
                                <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="student_id"
                                       value="Delete">
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <p><a href="add_student_form.php">Add Student</a></p>
            <p><a href="course_list.php">List courses</a></p>
        </section>

    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>

// database.php
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cs602';
$username = 'cs602*********';
$password = '************';

try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    include('../../../MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err');
    exit();
}
```

Here are some screenshots to better explain what's going on.

On initial page load:

[image]

After clicking cs602:

[image]

The boxes should've update with the relevant information from the database.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: your id is not an int  so you dont use this `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`

Comment: do not use `cs` in your `courseID` or don`t validate it as integer

Comment: That did it guys. Thanks for the help. First to make their comment as an answer gets the check lol